# Input the text into the HTML document using the Python

Tags: python, html

I have a simple HTML file with one row text. I need to have a **Python** script which will:
1. Ask the User to input his name
2. To insert the result to the end of the row

I read about CGI, frameworks, Python in HTML (this seemed me the easiest way) but I haven't succeed for now.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
 </head>
   <body><h1>Hi, my name is: <!--Here I need to have a result from the User's 
             input--></h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

Could you help me with the easiest solution or give hint, at least what I should ask Google? No JavaScript for this task, unfortunately

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take a look at Beautiful Soup for parsing HTML

https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/beautifulsoup-4-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a sweet tutorial about using [Jinja templating](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/) for you [here](https://code-maven.com/minimal-example-generating-html-with-python-jinja)

Comment: Sorry for mentioning this too late. This approach seems to be the most efficient in this particular case

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML, find the tag you want to replace the contents of and use the function replace_with to replace the text with the input. 
Or you can use Jinja2 as @James mentioned

[use this as reference for Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40775930/using-beautifulsoup-to-modify-html)

Answer (score -1):

i think you must try this ,, it will work :

in html file :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
 </head>
   <body><h1>Hi, my name is: {{ input }} </h1>
   </body>
</html>
```