# Append an attribute to input tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a simple HTML file that contains some input fields and other tags. My goal is to get all the `input` tags and append a new attribute `value` to each of them. It is to be noted that the value of this new attribute will be decided/populated from an array of strings.

I'm using the `BeautifulSoup` package of Python to parse this HTML file, and then append this new attribute to each of the `input` tags.

This my HTML file which I'm parsing:

**test.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Accessibility</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Hello World</h1>

    <div>
        <h2>This is a title</h2>
        <p>Welcome, to the world's first <strong>Accessibility Script</strong>. You will be amazed by it completely!<br>Hope you'll enjoy it!</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <form>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname">
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <strong><center>Let's begin here</center></strong>
    <hr>
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter your search keyword">
    <br><br>
    <textarea placeholder="Please enter your comments."></textarea>
    <button>Say Hello!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

So, how can I append a `value` attribute to each of the input tags in this HTML file using `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40775930/using-beautifulsoup-to-modify-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add it the same as you would for key/value in a dictionary:

**test_html:**

```
test_html = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Accessibility</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Hello World</h1>

    <div>
        <h2>This is a title</h2>
        <p>Welcome, to the world's first <strong>Accessibility Script</strong>. You will be amazed by it completely!<br>Hope you'll enjoy it!</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <form>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname">
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <strong><center>Let's begin here</center></strong>
    <hr>
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter your search keyword">
    <br><br>
    <textarea placeholder="Please enter your comments."></textarea>
    <button>Say Hello!</button>

</body>
</html>'''
```

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(test_html, 'html.parser')
input_tags = soup.find_all('input')

for each in input_tags:
    each['value'] = 'some_value'
```

**Output:**

```
print(str(soup))
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Accessibility</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<div>
<h2>This is a title</h2>
<p>Welcome, to the world's first <strong>Accessibility Script</strong>. You will be amazed by it completely!<br/>Hope you'll enjoy it!</p>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
<form>
<label>First Name</label>
<input name="fname" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="some_value"/>
<label>Last Name</label>
<input name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="some_value"/>
<label>Email</label>
<input name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" value="some_value"/>
<label>Phone Number</label>
<input name="fname" type="text" value="some_value"/>
</form>
</div>
<hr/>
<strong><center>Let's begin here</center></strong>
<hr/>
<input name="search" placeholder="Enter your search keyword" type="text" value="some_value"/>
<br/><br/>
<textarea placeholder="Please enter your comments."></textarea>
<button>Say Hello!</button>
</body>
</html>
```