# how to modify a saved html page?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to modify a saved html webpage. More specifically, I would like to highlight specific sentences in the page and save as a new html page.

I thought the code below would work but it does not

```
import re

#download https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML to disk using chrome / save as complete html
with open(r"C:\Users\Downloads\webpage.html", mode='rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:

    mytext = f.read()

    #highlight "The HyperText Markup Language, or HTML" in red
    re.sub("The HyperText Markup Language, or HTML", mytext,
           '<span style="color: red">{}</span>'.format(r'/1'))
    mytext.write(r"C:\Users\Downloads\webpage_modif.html")

  File "<ipython-input-9-f7f9195da80f>", line 5, in <module>
    mytext.write(r"C:\Users\Downloads\webpage_modif.html")

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: `mytext` is a string which holds the content of the html file. a string has no `write` method.

Comment: thanks! do you see an easy fix?

Comment: yes - open a file in `w` mode and write the str to the file

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. It is difficult in practice and theoretically impossible in principle. Look at `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40775930/using-beautifulsoup-to-modify-html) would be worth looking at

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. Can you post a simple answer that I can accept? thanks!

Comment: @balderman opening in `w` mode breaks at the `f.read()` live. Could you please post your solution? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can open html file, edit using `bs4` and write to the new file. I assume you are trying to add `style` attribute to the `span` tag:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML'
res = requests.get(url).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
text_to_be_highlighted = "The HyperText Markup Language, or HTML"
highlighed_text = f'<span style="color: red">{text_to_be_highlighted}</span>'


# grab all tags with specified text
tags = [tag for tag in soup.find_all(lambda tag: text_to_be_highlighted in tag.text)]

for tag in tags:
    new_text = tag.text.replace(text_to_be_highlighted, highlighed_text)
    tag.string = new_text


with open("new.html", "w", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    f.write(unescape(soup.prettify()))
```

Explanation: Grab all tags contains specified text with the help `find_all` method and `lambda` function. Get whole text and replace specified text with new tag that highlights that text. Finally, write modified `soup` to the new file

Comment: thanks but the issue is that my text can be part of a sentence or a paragraph (not necessarily a `span`). This is why the crude regex approach was probably OK. Does you example work on the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML ? Can you highlight ONLY the part  "The HyperText Markup Language, or HTML" ? thanks!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ, absolutely could be done. See the edits (used `xml.sax.saxutils.unescape` to prevent html to convert `<` and `>` into `lt`, `gt`)

Comment: thanks! I had to replace the last line by `with open("new.html", "w", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:` to avoid encoding issues but strangely enough the file new.html only contains text (its not the same html page anymore). What I want to get is the same html page with with some elements of text highlighted

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ, instead of reading from local file, I just parsed wiki url and result was okay. Try the edit

Comment: are you able to open new.html in a browser? does it look like the original page to you?

Comment: It won't and shouldn't look the same since css and js files are not provided

Comment: ah sorry then, I should have mentioned that. I would like the output to look like the same exact original page, but with the highlighted text in addition. Do you see some possible solution maybe? perhaps using `requests` directly like you did?

Comment: I don't think it is possible unless you smh get exact css/js files from wiki :). But technically it is the same html with highlighted text

Comment: that is fine, the main objective is achieved. I will create a separate question for this